# Does a sequence f($a_n$) converge, if f is continuous and $a_n$ is a convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

The exact wording of the question is as follows:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ a convergen series. Does the sequence ($f(a_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ converge, and if so, to which limit?

**What I have tried**

$a_n$ converges $\rightarrow$ $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ $\\$
$\rightarrow \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f(a_n) = f(L)$ $\\$
However, that seems to be a bit easy, so I am wondering whether or not this is mathematically sound.

Comment: In this context, the question is probably asking you to re-show the fact that the limit is $f(L)$.

Comment: One of the (equivalent) definitions of continuity for a metric space (e.g., $\mathbb{R})$ is that any convergent sequence $x_n \to x$ has $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. If you're using something like the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of the limit (again, in a space like $\mathbb{R}$), then you can unwind that definition to get the one above.

Comment: @BrunoB so you think that they want me to prove that the limit of f($a_n$) is indeed f(L)?

Comment: What would happen if $f$ were not continuous? What you have now use just an assertion where it is not even clear why the continuity of $f$ matters.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis So I should use the fact that for continuous functions $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) $?